# What is the geometric interpretation of the following basic result of Euclidean inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

My linear algebra textbook has this as a theorem:

$u\cdot v = \frac{1}{4}\|u+v\|^2 - \frac{1}{4}\|{u-v}\|^2$

for vectors $u$ and $v.$ All I can see is that the diagonal length of parallelogram made up with $u$ and $v$ is longer than the length of other diagonal when the angle created by $u$ and $v$ is acute. The similar argument goes in case it is obtuse. Is there any other significant geometric interpretation?

Comment: Thank you for the editing.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\|u\|=\|v\|=1$. Then the length of each diagonal of the parallelogram that you mentioned lies between $0$ and $2$. So, if you compute the *square* of the length of the diagonal made up with $u$ and $v$ and then you subtract from it the square of the length of the other diagonal, you get a number between $-4$ and $4$. The equality from your question means that if you divide this number by $4$ (thereby getting a number in $[-1,1]$), then what you get is the cosine of the angle between $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I know it is possible to show, but this theorem seems only applied to the Euclidean inner product because the divisor 4 seems attributed to how the norm in this space is calculated (L2).